# Inserting Multiple Rows by Form into a Single DB

Tags: php, mysql, insert

First time doing this, watch it be a really obvious/easy fix...

Basically I'm trying to insert multiple rows with a single insert query, however, I clearly fail and as such it wont work.

The form is generated by searching a table for the relevant entries it relates to, so if your in department A it will grab your name and form an input line on the form. This all works fine I can generate the form however the issue them comes when I try to insert the form.

Currently it does this thing where rather than inserting the data entered via the form it is entering the letter A across most fields (COUNT, STATUS and TYPE are immune to this as they are restricted to only certain data types via the tables set up itself).

This is currently how I have the form set in the script:

```
<?php
if ($action == "editrecord") {
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="left">
<?php //Getting Title for Record
        $resultTITLE = queryDB("SELECT * FROM merit_subdepts WHERE subdeptID = '$subdeptID'");
        while($rowTITLE = mysql_fetch_array($resultTITLE)) {
        $recordTITLE = $rowTITLE["subdeptNAME"];
            echo "$recordTITLE";
        }
?>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Member Name</td><td>Choose Award</td><td>Reason</td><td></td></tr>
<?php
        $resultMERIT = queryDB("SELECT * FROM merit_members WHERE memberPRIMARY = '$subdeptID'");
        while($rowMERIT = mysql_fetch_array($resultMERIT)) {
        $memberID = $rowMERIT["memberID"];  
        $memberNAME = $rowMERIT["memberNAME"];
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $memberNAME; ?></td>
                <td><select name="count[]" class="ui-state-default">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input name="reason[]" type="text" id="reason" class="blackInput" value="Monthly Award <?php echo date("F, Y") ?>"></td> 
                <td><input name="type[]" type="hidden" id="type" value="Civil">
                    <input name="awarder[]" type="hidden" id="awarder" value="<?php $usersname; ?>">
                    <input name="datea[]" type="hidden" id="datea" value="<?php $stamp83; ?>">
                    <input name="status[]" type="hidden" id="status" value="Check">
                    <input name="id[]" type="hidden" id="id" value"<?php $memberID; ?>">
                    <input name="dept[]" type="hidden" id="dept" value"<?php $recordTITLE; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>

        <?php } //end of sub-division membership list ?>
<tr><td colspan="4"><center>
       <div class="butDiv"><input name="submitRECORDS" type="submit" id="submitRECORDS" value="Submit Records"></div>
       </center>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
} //End of Edit Merit Records
?>
```

This is the insert query used:

```
if ($submitRECORDS) {

for($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['id']); $i++) //Getting total # var submitted and running loop 
{ $fromID = $_POST['id'][$i]; //var
  $fromTYPE = $_POST['type'][$i]; //var
  $fromCOUNT = $_POST['count'][$i]; //var
  $fromDATEA = $_POST['datea'][$i]; //var
  $fromAWARDER = $_POST['awarder'][$i]; //var
  $fromREASON = $_POST['reason'][$i]; //var
  $fromDEPT = $_POST['dept'][$i]; //var
  $fromSTATUS = $_POST['status'][$i]; //var
if ($fromID != "0") { 
queryDB("INSERT INTO merit_precord (NAME,TYPE,COUNT,DATEA,AWARDER,REASON,DEPT,STATUS) VALUES ('$fromID','$fromTYPE','$fromCOUNT','$fromDATEA','$fromAWARDER','$fromREASON','$fromDEPT',$fromSTATUS')"); } }
$action="";
$msg=1;
}
```

Assistance much appreciated before I rip my hair out. :)

Comment: Read about PDO, bindParam and Transactions.

Comment: on your submit code, do `print_r($_POST); exit;` just to see if the results are coming across properly.  If that looks good, echo your SQL query you're running to make sure that looks right. Also look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php to protect your SQL

Comment: thanks, i shored up the injection issue, i knew it was there but i was more interested in getting it working before i secured it fully.  i also ran print_r($_POST); you suggested and i got this in response: Array ( [count] => Array [reason] => Array [type] => Array [awarder] => Array [datea] => Array [status] => Array [id] => Array [dept] => Array [submitRECORDS] => Submit Records )

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only source of your problems (only the first I notice), but when using `<?php $varname ?>`, nothing will actually be printed to the screen.  Instead you need to use `<?php echo $varname; ?>`

```
            <td><input name="type[]" type="hidden" id="type" value="Civil">
                <input name="awarder[]" type="hidden" id="awarder" value="<?php echo $usersname; ?>">
                <input name="datea[]" type="hidden" id="datea" value="<?php echo $stamp83; ?>">
                <input name="status[]" type="hidden" id="status" value="Check">
                <input name="id[]" type="hidden" id="id" value"<?php echo $memberID; ?>">
                <input name="dept[]" type="hidden" id="dept" value"<?php echo $recordTITLE; ?>">
            </td>
```

The `A` you're seeing inserted is the first letter of `Array`.  When the above values are inserted empty and you try to access them in the for loop with `[]`, the string `Array` is accessed by character index like an array.

Your `INSERT` statements, as mentioned in comments, are vulnerable to SQL injection.  Escape them with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
  $fromID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$i]);
  $fromTYPE = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type'][$i]);
  $fromCOUNT = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['count'][$i]);
  ...
  ...  
  $fromSTATUS = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status'][$i]);
```